# Installing ns-allinone-2.29.3 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, networking, ns2, octal

I am trying to install ns-allinone-2.29 on Ubuntu 14.04 but i get the following error :

configure: error: otcl is required but could not be completely found.
Please correct the problem by telling configure where otcl is
using the argument --with-otcl=/path/to/package,
or the package is not required, disable it with --with-otcl=no.
tclcl-1.17 configuration failed! Exiting ...
Please check http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ns-problems.html
for common problems and bug fixes.

Comment: Please edit your question to show information about the extra protocol you are trying to add with "the ./configure in ns-2.29/"

Comment: I am actually interested about Study of the performance of the handover process in a heterogeneous network environment.